# Where does Android Account Manager store account specific preferences?

Tags: android, accounts, account-management

I've been successful in creating various account authenticators / services each with their own preference.xml.  These preferences are persistent but I do not know where on the phone they are stored.  I've scoured the phone using adb but I can't seem to find a *.db or "shared_prefs" files that corresponds to the preferences for my particular accounts.

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 9):

I wondered the same thing, as I was searching for where android stored the Bundle "extras" with the account.

It's in a SQLite database (you'll need to root your phone to extract and browse it):

```
/data/system/users/0/accounts.db
```

You'll need to find your account for your app:

```
sqlite> select * from accounts;
24|john.doe|com.evernote|
```

Then use the id to find the extras:

```
sqlite> select * from extras where accounts_id = 24;
70|24|userId|8305749
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, `/data/system/users/0/accounts.db` is not really used anymore on current android versions.

I found all my account data in `/data/system_de/0/accounts_de.db`.

Additionally quite a bit of google authentication info seems to be cached in `/data/system_ce/0/accounts_ce.db`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not, because normally you don't have to care about where android stores the shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [custom account preference activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888411/404597), `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` shows that the default preferences are stored in the preference folder for the **application package**. For example, if you have

```
    <manifest package="com.my.app.account" ... >
```

The settings are stored in

```
    /data/data/com.my.app.account/shared_prefs/com.my.package.account_preferences.xml
```

These results are from the Android 2.3 emulator.