# ActivityNotFoundException when different package's targetClass in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, package, preference

The application's default package is "example.app".

and the target activity's package is "example.app.abc".

Calling startActivity() for "example.app.abc.TheActivity" in java code just works,

but specifying it on preference.xml doesn't work:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:key="key"
    android:title="@string/title"
>
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
        android:targetPackage="example.app.abc"
        android:targetClass="TheActivity"
/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I tried android:targetClass="example.app.abc.TheActivity" but it doesn't work too.

Is it impossible to start an activity of non-default package, in preference?

Comment: I don know if its possible to start a non default package. Whydont u try again with a "." in front of the targetClass. like android:targetClass=".TheActivity"

Comment: Where do you see the nested `<intent>` feature documented?

Comment: It should not be documented, as it's unsupported internal API. The application might be rejected by using it.

Comment: I didn't know it's undocumented API. My friend's app actually uses the above technique and runs well with the default package's activity.

Comment: @Pentium10: It is not undocumented, as you can find it in the API Demos project as an example.

Comment: same issue here.. ever found an answer?

Comment: @CommonsWare It is mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Intents)

Answer (score 30):

I just ran into the same problem when trying to use a [custom preference screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10854060/404597) from a library project for the AccountManager account settings. No matter how I tried to tweak the targetPackage and targetClass attributes, it would throw an exception (except, since it's an account, it crashes the phone).

I think we'll just have to assume this is an Android limitation. It's clumsy, but all you really need to do is declare a wrapper class for the activity within your application's namespace:

```
public class MyPreferences extends ActualPreferences {
}
```

Declare it in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MyPreferences"/>
```

Then you can specify the class in your intent

```
<intent android:targetPackage="com.my.package"
        android:targetClass="com.my.package.MyPreferences" />
```

By the way, **the syntax is extremely fussy**, at least for account preferences. All these variations fail:

```
<!-- fails --> <intent android:targetClass="com.my.package.MyPreferences" />
<!-- fails --> <intent android:targetClass="MyPreferences" 
                       android:targetPackage="com.my.package"/>
<!-- fails --> <intent android:targetClass=".MyPreferences"
                       android:targetPackage="com.my.package"/>
<!-- fails --> <intent android:targetClass="settings.MyPreferences"
                       android:targetPackage="com.my.package"/>
<!-- fails --> <intent android:targetClass=".settings.MyPreferences"
                       android:targetPackage="com.my.package"/>
<!-- fails --> <intent android:targetClass="com.my.other.package.MyPreferences"
                       android:targetPackage="com.my.package"/>
```

The critical factor is apparently that the `android:targetPackage` attribute matches the application package. If you want, you can put the activity in a sub-package. This works:

```
<intent android:targetPackage="com.my.package"
        android:targetClass="com.my.package.settings.MyPreferences" />
```

Comment: So you declared com.mypackage.MyPreferences.java, but you wrote targetClass="com.my.package.settings.MyPreferences", and it worked?

Answer (score 1):

as already said its not working with libraries. Do it programatically, something like this:

```
preference_my_pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, ActivityToStart.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: you might wanna copy the extras from the original intent like `newIntent.putExtras(oldIntent)`