# Weird ActivityNotFoundException for class in a library project

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-activity

I am getting an `ActivityNotFoundException` for an activity which exists and is included in my applications `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Here is my scenario:

My Application project package is: `com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.android`.

My library project package is `com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.common`

My library project is properly included in my application project as I can use other classes in the library project from within my application project.

The activity `MyTedAdvancedPreference` is found in my library project under `com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.common.prefs` package.

In my application project, I have an xml, `res/xml/prefs.xml`, where I have defined preferences, including a preference screen to call `MyTedAdvancedPreference` as shown below:

```
    <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/config_cat_advanced" >
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.android"
            android:targetClass="com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.common.prefs.MyTedAdvancedPreferences"/>
```

Note that MyTedAdvancedPreferences is included in my application project AndroidManifest.xml as :

```
  <application
   .....
   <activity android:name="com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.common.prefs.MyTedAdvancedPreference"
       android:label="@string/title_settings"
         android:theme="@style/MyApplynxTheme" >       
    </activity>
   ....
   </application>
```

My application compiles and runs OK. So when I access my settings page and try to access `MyTedAdvancedPreference`, I get an `ActivityNotFoundException`:

```
10-25 14:15:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(19049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 14:15:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(19049): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:   Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.android/com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.common.prefs.MyTedAdvancedPreferences}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

The activity is defined in my applications(`com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.android`) `AndroidManifest.xml`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please Post your whole manifest file.

Comment: check Build Path -> Order/Export - make sure that Private Libraries are marked for export

Comment: Hi Tomislav, that was already done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks similar to another question [ActivityNotFoundException when different package's targetClass in PreferenceScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360100/activitynotfoundexception-when-different-packages-targetclass-in-preferencescre?rq=1)

Here is the answer that describes a workaround, suggesting that this is a bug in the framework:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888411/383414

What he suggests is inheriting from the "broken" Activity, placing the inherited code inside your main app project. Then reference that as per normal in your main manifest.

Comment: I never thought this as a bug, thanks for pointing it out. Hope it gets fixed. I appreciate your answer.Thanks.

Comment: you would click on the "tick" icon to the left of the answer, just below the "votes" number. thx

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest change this:

```
   <activity android:name="com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.common.prefs.MyTedAdvancedPreference"
   android:label="@string/title_settings"
     android:theme="@style/MyApplynxTheme" >       
</activity>
```

to this:

```
   <activity
            android:name="MyTedAdvancedPreference"
            android:label="@string/title_settings"
            android:theme="@style/MyApplynxTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.action.ACTION_PREF_ACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And your pref.screen should look like this:

```
    <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/config_cat_advanced" >
        <intent android:action="example.action.ACTION_PREF_ACTIVITY" >
        </intent>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: @nmvictor I updated the answer, the `action android:name` should be equal to the action you are defining in your pref.screen. I you need any help with this let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Intent-Filter and give the

**Action(com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.common.prefs).**

```
  <application
       .....
       <activity android:name="com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.common.prefs.MyTedAdvancedPreference"
           android:label="@string/title_settings"
             android:theme="@style/MyApplynxTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.common.prefs" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>       
        </activity>
       ....
       </application>
```

**And try to call Activity like**

```
Intent intent=new Intent("com.myapplynx.mytexteditor.common.prefs");//action
intent.startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it should work.

Comment: not exactly what I am looking to achieve since I need to call the activity from the prefs.xml. Unless you gave an example with that. Thanks though.